# Getting a 403 error involving CSRF when trying to connect to localhost (python requests)

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to test a connection to one of my Django views using Python's `requests` library. When I try to make a `POST` request on it I receive info when viewing `request.text` telling me the CSRF verification failed, and that I need a CSRF token when submitting forms. I've done some more research here and tried my best with this

This is my code right now:

```
post_request = requests.session()
post_request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/')
csrftoken = post_request.cookies['csrftoken']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36'}
final_request = post_request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/', headers=dict(Referer=post_request))
```

This is my view:

```
def add_message(request):
    form = InputInfoForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('hey')

    return HttpResponse('test')
```

So how do I verify the CSRF token in the view using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is the following. 
Django expects you to have the CSRFTOKEN in your cookie, but a post data must be provided with a name of csrfmiddlewaretoken to your post parameters too. so, using the python request method,

```
post_request = requests.session()
post_request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/')
csrftoken = post_request.cookies['csrftoken']
#now the csrftoken cookie is stored in csrftoken
final_request = post_request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/', data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken}, cookies=post_request.cookies) #assuming the post data for your form is empty, else add in the 'data' dictionary. just check your 'InputInfoForm' form for any fields. 
final_request.text  #will read you the data returned from the view, in your case "hey"
```

in your view, make the following changes,

```
from django.shortcuts import render  #needed
def add_message(request):
    form = InputInfoForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('hey')

    return render(request, 'test.html')  #assuming no context...
```

in your app folder, add a 'templates' folder and create 'test.html' file inside templates. then add the following

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'message:test'%}">{%csrf_token%}</form>
```

then inside the project folder's urls.py, add

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
urlpatterns = [
#admin_page --snip--
url(r'^message/', include('APPNAME.urls', namespace='message')),
]
```

then inside your app folder, create a 'urls.py' file and add the following ...

```
from .views import add_message #your view
from django.conf.urls import url

app_name = "APP_NAME"  #from django2.0 on wards 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', add_message, name='test'), 
]
```

then you are good to go. check by running your python code as above.

Comment: It's still not working for me, I've seemed to be able to isolate the problem. When I run `r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/')` for example It shows an empty set: `<RequestsCookieJar[]>` So it doesn't look like I'm getting the cookies

Comment: in your templates, have you included the {%csrf_token%} inside the post form tag?? or any deletion or removal of middle wares will make your pages render without any csrftoken cookies. check that too.

Comment: Nope I'm doing this without templates

Comment: then how can you have any cookies or page rendered without a template??

Comment: I'm not rendering a page I'm just using the models to add to a Db. And using requests to do so. As for the cookie I wasn't sure if I needed a template for one

Comment: That's a good idea, I was so fixated on not using templates I didn't think to just make a dummy one. Cheers I'll try that then check back

Comment: Hey sorry was just trying it out, it's working great. That last "cookies" argument in the .post() function is new to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165460/discussion-between-menilik-belay-and-amon).

Answer (score 1):

You should send CSRF token in POST data

```
r = post_request.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/', 
    data={'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken},
    headers=dict(Referer=URL)
)
```

Alternative way to send CSRF token would be through header

```
r = post_request.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/', 
    headers={'Referer': URL, 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken)
)
```

`HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` is a default value of `settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME`

Comment: Okay and do I need to replace `csrftoken` with the actual csrftoken in the cookies?

Comment: nvm that question, but i still seem to be getting the error

Comment: I'm getting an invalid syntax error at `csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken` isn't that supposed to be a dictionary?

Comment: @Amon yes it should be dict

Comment: Still getting the issue, no idea what the problem is

Comment: @Amon what is the issue you are getting

Comment: The same one that tells me the CSRF isn't valid. However I just realized I'm doing something potentially stupid. I'm running this code a a django file that is being served by the same host giving me the error. In other words the server isn't even running and yet I'm trying to make a request to it

Comment: @Amon you don't seem to be displaying form on GET which is why you are probably missing csrftoken cookie
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: I may have isolated the issue, when I try to retrieve the csrftoken in `post_request.cookies['csrftoken']` I'm getting this error: `KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))`

Comment: I see, that wont require I use any HTML templates right? I'm just trying to use requests. What you're saying is that I should construct the form in my view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165445/discussion-between-iklinac-and-amon).